# pl/sql: select as argument/parameter of function in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, parameters, plsql, arguments

I've got problem with creating function. I'll try explain what the problem is:

The task is about creating function which is based on `select first_name from employees where dept_id=10;`. New function MUST have v_select_statement (which I wrote) as argument(sth like this: `v_select_statement := select first_name from employees where dept_id=10;`. Selet like you can see generating list of names. These names should be in new table which is created in this function too. New table should have name e.g new_table.
Problem is that I don't know how to do it. I tried something like this:

```
create or replace

FUNCTION create_new_tab (v_select_statement VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
is
b first_name.employees%TYPE;

begin

--here i don`t know how to assign select statement to cursor or execute immediate. Any ideas? i tried create sth like:
-- execute immediate 'v_select_statement into b ';


execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE new_tab (i VARCHAR2(50))';
execute immediate 'insert into new_tab values (statement_result)';
--don`t know how and what to put as statement_result. I know that i could use cursor, but ---how in this case?
return 1;

exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
return 0;

END create_new_tab
;
```

Can you help me, because I give up. I have no idea how to solve this problem.
Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following:

```
create or replace FUNCTION create_new_tab (v_select_statement VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
is
b employees.first_name%TYPE;
cur SYS_REFCURSOR;

begin
OPEN cur for v_select_statement;

execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE new_tab (i VARCHAR2(50))';

LOOP
    FETCH cur into b;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    execute immediate 'insert into new_tab values (:statement_result)' USING b;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
return 1;

exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
return 0;

END create_new_tab
;
```

Couldn't test it without the tables but it may point you in the right direction.
But as Avrajit already said, I would suggest creating the `new_tab` beforehand and then insert into that table normalle without Dynamic-SQL.
You also have to keep in mind, that this function can only be run once, as it will result in an error if you try to create the table when it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Function created for your referenec.
    What i suggest you to create a table beforehand and then
    try to insert data into it. Please try this code and let me
    know if it works for you. Thanks

```
Create or replace function test_func return number
as
cursor cr is select name from avrajit 
where department='.NET';
name_av avrajit.name%type;
begin
for rec in cr
loop
insert into av_test(dpt) values(rec.name);
return 1;
end loop;
exception 
when others then
return 0;
end test_func;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is purpose of your function.  But if you still want to do try this

```
create or replace

FUNCTION create_new_tab (v_select_statement VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
is
b first_name.employees%TYPE;

begin

--here i don`t know how to assign select statement to cursor or execute immediate. Any ideas? i tried create sth like:
-- execute immediate 'v_select_statement into b ';


execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE new_tab (i VARCHAR2(50))';
execute immediate 'insert into new_tab values ( ' ||  v_select_statement || ' )';    --don`t know how and what to put as statement_result. I know that i could use cursor, but ---how in this case?
return 1;

exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
return 0;

END create_new_tab
;`
```